# How do I find the exact match in R without the other similar patterns?

Tags: r, exact-match

```
index   chr  
1       chr1
2       chr1
3       chr10
4       chr10
```

code:

```
for (i in chr_size)
{
  chr_1 = chr[i]
  idx1 = grep("chr1", chr, fixed = TRUE)
}
```

this results in showing all 4 indices. I just want 1 and 2.

my file is large and in form of a matrix

Comment: If your actual data is a matrix, then what does your expected output look like here?

Comment: Have a look at match.

Comment: As @Christoph said, `match` would probably be what you are looking for. If you want to use a regex though, `grep("^chr1$", chr)`.

Comment: @Mikko Marttila i tried using grep("^chr1$", chr) but it shows no result.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want the total number of index that matches "chr1"

Comment: if you want exact don't use `grep` use `==` `sum(chr== "chr1")`

Comment: @s.brunel I want exact match. I want the total no.of chr1 repeating, total no. of chr2 repeating and so on

Comment: thank you all. I found another syntax which("chr1"==chr)